# JavaScript Redirect Issue

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, cross-platform

I'm building a cross-platform app with JavaScript. I want to redirect to a different page (in a different domain) but it is not working. I tried:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function redir() {
      window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="redir()">

</body>

</html>
```

It gived me a blank page. I tried with a different code, I tried `iframe` like this:

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <iframe src="http://www.example.com" />
</body>

</html>
```

But it didn't worked again. It gave me a blank iframe. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you want to redirect to another page on click or simply when the objects load?

Comment: @kdyz I want to redirect when someone came into this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function Redirect() {
  window.location="https://www.tutorialspoint.com";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Redirect Me" onclick="Redirect();" />
</form>
```

Comment: I don't want to do like this. I want to redirect when someone comes to the page. I don't want to do this with a button.

Comment: just call this function  on body load :D

Comment: Use "window.location" not "window.location.href"

Answer (score -1):

```
<body onload="redir()"></body>
```

Comment: I did the same on the top